# The effective way to do some calculation between every 2 columns in a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example, i need to calculate the conditional probability for every pair (x, y) where x from col1, and y from col2. It's not very difficult if i use:

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy("col1", "col2").count()
```

Then i got:

```
 +----+-----+-----+
 |col1|col2 |count|
 +----+-----+-----+
 | A  |[Non]| 1185|
 | B  |[Non]| 4609|
 | B  |[Oui]|  830|
 | A  |[Oui]|  177|
 +--- +-----+-----+
```

But since i have more than 2 columns, i need a loop to store all the results. Mainly, i want a map likes `x -> (y, count)` for each line, and then an array for all the columns.
So, my questions are:

What is the most effective way to do that?

1. Likes the code above (use `dataframe` and `groupBy + count`. Then, how to `collectAsMap`? And i should use DataFrame's API or RDD's API? My input is a dataframe.
2. Collect all the data first, i.e., in a 2-dimension array then do the calculation.
3. or some other better idea?

Comment: can you elaborate with three columns or more columns sample data and an expected output?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan For three columns c1, c2, c3, i need the count between (c1, c2), (c1, c3), (c2, c3). Hence, execute the code above 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

First option will be the choice in your case. Keep in mind the all collect functions in spark(collect, collectAsMap, etc) triggers a spark action, computation over the cluster. Do your computation first(map-reduce on your dataframe) and when you have a result that needs to be output do a collect on the dataframe/rdd. 
You can also do a collectAsMap, but another approach is to define your results in a case class:

```
case class Result(col1: Int, col2:Int, count:Long)
df2.map(row => Result( col1 = row.getAsInt[Int]("col1"), col2 = row.getAsInt[Int]("col2"), count = row.getAsLong[Long]("count"))
```

After that you do a collect on df2 and you have a List[Result] and can do a foreach to treat each element.